# What are the ways to resolve npm run dev error?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, server

I deployed my Laravel version 7 project on Hostinger. I managed to set up my project and installed node using nvm but when I run `npm run dev`, it just won't execute.

I tried to execute:
`npm cache clean --force`
`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
`npm install`

and `npm rebuild`

but nothing changes and the error is still there.

Here is my error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/u618667693/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/u618667693/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'prod'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preprod', 'prod', 'postprod' ]
5 info lifecycle @~preprod: @
6 info lifecycle @~prod: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~prod: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~prod: PATH: /home/u618667693/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/u618667693/domains/expensetracker.site/expense-tracker/node_modules/.bin:/home/u618667693/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle @~prod: CWD: /home/u618667693/domains/expensetracker.site/expense-tracker
10 silly lifecycle @~prod: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run production' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~prod: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~prod: Failed to exec prod script
13 verbose stack Error: @ prod: `npm run production`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/u618667693/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/u618667693/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /home/u618667693/domains/expensetracker.site/expense-tracker
16 verbose Linux 4.18.0-147.8.1.el7h.lve.1.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/home/u618667693/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node" "/home/u618667693/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm" "run" "prod"
18 verbose node v14.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ prod: `npm run production`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ prod script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.32.13",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@mdi/font": "^5.9.55",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^1.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "numeral": "^2.0.6",
        "pdfmake": "^0.1.71",
        "randomcolor": "^0.6.2",
        "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
        "vuetify": "^2.5.0",
        "vuetify-confirm": "^2.0.6",
        "vuetify-dialog": "^2.0.14",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2",
        "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: failed at `npm run production`